# Hashmap Sorting in ascending order

Tags: java, list, hashmap

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Dog dog1 = new Dog();
        dog1.setName("Lab");
        dog1.setAge(3);

        Dog dog2 = new Dog();
        dog2.setName("Beagle");
        dog2.setAge(1);

        Dog dog3 = new Dog();
        dog3.setName("Golden");
        dog3.setAge(6);

        Dog dog4 = new Dog();
        dog4.setName("German");
        dog4.setAge(4);

        Dog dog5 = new Dog();
        dog5.setName("Husky");
        dog5.setAge(2);

        List<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<>();
        dogList.add(dog1);
        dogList.add(dog2);
        dogList.add(dog3);
        dogList.add(dog4);
        dogList.add(dog5);
        Collections.sort(dogList);
        System.out.println(dogList);

        List<Cat> catList = new ArrayList<>();
        catList.add(new Cat("cat1", 2));
        catList.add(new Cat("cat2", 6));
        catList.add(new Cat("cat3", 7));
        catList.add(new Cat("cat4", 4));
        catList.add(new Cat("cat5", 3));
        Collections.sort(catList);
        System.out.println(catList);
        
        Map<Integer, Integer> ageMap = new HashMap<>();
  }
}
```

After sorting, I would like to insert the following key-value pairs in a `HashMap` - `<Cat age, Dog age>`.

Comment: Hello, can you please clarify which output do you expect for your input data, that is, how do you expect to match cat's age to the dog's age ?  Or you need to have only one entry: `ageMap.put(catList.get(0), dogList.get(0))`?

Comment: Output as {2=1, 3=2, 4=3, 6=4, 7=6}   Minimum age of cat should pair with minimum age of dog

Comment: do `Dog` and `Cat` implement `Comparable` interface to be properly sorted by Age?

Comment: I was able to sort respective lists      [Dog [name=Beagle, age=1], Dog [name=Husky, age=2], Dog [name=Lab, age=3], Dog [name=German, age=4], Dog [name=Golden, age=6]]
[Cat [name=cat1, age=2], Cat [name=cat5, age=3], Cat [name=cat4, age=4], Cat [name=cat2, age=6], Cat [name=cat3, age=7]]

Comment: @Vineesh Welcome to the community. Before posting any question, please go through [basic formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) guide and [general etiquette](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking questions.

Comment: @Vineesh- please provide the Cat and Dog class also.

Comment: Kindly edit your Question to include clarifications. Do not add those in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing that both lists `catList` and `dogList` are properly sorted by age, the map can be populated with a simple loop.

```java
for (int i = 0, n = Math.min(catList.size(), dogList.size()); i < n; i++) {
    Cat cat = catList.get(i);
    Dog dog = dogList.get(i);
    ageMap.put(cat.getAge(), dog.getAge());
}
```

Solution with iterators:

```java
Iterator<Cat> itCat = catList.iterator();
Iterator<Dog> itDog = dogList.iterator();

while (itCat.hasNext() && itDog.hasNext()) {
    ageMap.put(itCat.next().getAge(), itDog.next().getAge());
}
```

*Note: in order to maintain the order of entries in the `ageMap` it is better to replace `HashMap` with `TreeMap` which is sorted by keys, or `LinkedHashMap` which maintains order of insertion, but in our case the insertion will be ordered.*

```java
Map<Integer, Integer> ageMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

Comment: Can we use iterator here?

Comment: Sure, iterators or streams are also applicable

Answer (score 0):

This is the ideal way to do this in java 8. Apologies for typo if any, in syntax.

```
List<Dog> dogList = 
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Dog::getAge));

List<Cat> catList = 
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Cat::getAge));

Map<Integer, Integer> ageMap = new HashMap<>();

int index= catList.size()-1;
if(dogList.size()==catList.size()){
 dogList.forEach(dog -> {
    ageMap.put(dog.getAge(), catList.get(index).getAge());
    index--;
});
}
```